# How to Get Graphics Object Width Using createjs Framework in Html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

How to get graphics object width or text width using createjs or easeljs.

```
Graphics Obj : 

var myShape = new createjs.Shape();
myShape .graphics.beginStroke("#FFFFFF");
myShape .graphics.setStrokeStyle(5);
myShape .graphics.beginFill("#C1272D").drawRect(0, 0, gameStage.canvas.width - 10, 40);
stage.addChild(myShape);

Text Field :

var textF = new createjs.Text("Time Left.. Do it Fast", "20px Arial", "#FFFFFF");
stage.addChild(textF);
```

How can I retrieve the dimensions (width & height) of textF and myShape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is (currently) no way of getting a calculated way of a Shape, implementing this in JavaScript would be way to slow.

The dimensions of a text can be retrieved via: `getMeasuredWidth()` and `getMeasuredHeight()`
http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Text.html

Comment: You can do this yourself but for performance reasons the is no generic way of calculating the dimensions of a Shape