# How to Get Display Object width using createjs framework in html5

Tags: html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

How to get Display Object using createjs or easeljs.

Graphics Obj :

```
 var myShape = new createjs.Shape();
 myShape .graphics.beginStroke("#FFFFFF");
 myShape .graphics.setStrokeStyle(5);
 myShape .graphics.beginFill("#C1272D").drawRect(0, 0, gameStage.canvas.width - 10, 40);
 stage.addChild(myShape);
```

Text Field :

```
var textF = new createjs.Text("Time Left.. Do it Fast", "20px Arial", "#FFFFFF");
stage.addChild(textF);
```

So please tell me, how to get textF and myShape object width....???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get Graphics Object Width Using createjs Framework in Html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317799/how-to-get-graphics-object-width-using-createjs-framework-in-html5)

Answer (score 0):

For the TextF have a look at this [EaselJS Online Docs : getMeasuredWidth Method](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Text.html#method_getMeasuredWidth)

For Shape [EaselJS Online Docs : getBounds Method](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_getBounds)